# Viewsheds analysis with real life photos?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm doing viewsheds presentation for a non-software audience this week. One of the ways I will try to get closer to them is by putting photos from my personal observations from a location + the viewsheds analysis derived from personal computational methods in my presentation.

Is there another, alternative option that I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use ArcGis Pro since it has 3D capabilites. Add the results of your viewshed and place "yourself" in the 3D map at the center of the viewshed analysis. Then compare the view and the viewshed results to the photographs. ArcGis Pro is free when you have a ArcGIS Desktop license

EDIT: I found an image of a viewshed analysis that i made in GRASS and displayed in ArcGIS Pro some time ago. The center of the Viewshed is the red dot to the right. If you place yourself at the red dot all you should see is green:
[image]

Comment: Since I was looking for an answer with "viewsheds vs real-life observations" concept, this one was the closest. However, both of them are of great help!

Comment: Excellent example. I guess this is cumulative viewshed because there are two red dots (one in the center, and one to the right).

Comment: No the center dot is just a location marker. I wanted to find out if the right dot was visible from the center dot

Comment: Oh okay, maybe it's an optical illusion from my side, but I'm not sure that some of the raster cells are actually visible from the center dot (like the hill down from the center dot; it's not possible this side of the hill to be visible from the center dot). Like I said, maybe it's just an optical illusion I'm having.

Comment: The analysis was not made from the center dot, it was made from the dot to the right, 150 m above DEM level

Answer (score 3):

If you have an ArcGIS Online account I think this is a good use of their story maps.  They give you custom widgets to embed almost exactly what I think you are talking about, you can create a photo walk through a site with pictures along the way. You can set up custom pop-ups or visualizations, and many other cool things.  There are also several different custom apps like Story Map Cascade and Story Map shortlist you may find helpful as well.

You can share these web apps/maps to many different people, without them having to have ArcGIS installed on their desktop.

https://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/

https://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/cascade/

https://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/shortlist/